# Installing packages with pip

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I have been advised using pip in a Anaconda virtual environment is bad. But some packages are not on conda or on conda forge.

When I run

```
conda activate virtualenv
where pip
```

I get two paths, one which is outside the environment

```
C:\Anaconda\virtualenv\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip.exe
```

How do I fix it, so that when I do pip install package it only installs in the virtual environment?

Comment: What's to be fixed? When you run `pip` from inside the virtual environment, only the first `pip.exe` in the list will be executed, which will install the package inside the env (unless something's misconfigured or I've misunderstood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line should use the first `pip` it finds, which in your case is the one in the virtual environment. This `pip` will only install packages in your environment. You can check which one is running with `pip --version`.